# How to change the copy quality to draft mode for copy for the epson SX100

Tags: printer

I'm trying to change the quality of copy for my epson stylus SX100. The [online manual](http://support.epson-europe.com/onlineguides/en/sx100series/html/index.htm) does not give a clue on how to do that. I know this is quite simple on the espon XP 415 as there is a screen and a menu. The only operation I want to do for now is copying documents.

EDIT: this question address the copy using only this multifunction printer (no computer).

Comment: Draft mode is entirely a print function rather than a scan function.  If there isn't a built-in quality setting for the copy function, you might be able to temporarily set the print quality to draft and see if the copy function honors that.  Another option: look at some of the free photocopy utilities downloadable online.  One of those may have a quality setting.

Comment: @fixer1234 I already tried to set draft mode for printing but this setting only affects printing done with this computer (test done with 1 desktop and 2 laptops, 2 microsoft OS and 1 linux, all both with wi-fi and USB). The photocopy utilities work well -- as they only are a scan utility feeding a print utility whose settings are easily modified -- but need to use a computer which is something I want to avoid (for multiples reasons).

Comment: I've run into similar situations with some all-in-ones.  The built-in copy function often doesn't have many options.  Sometimes the bundled software has a more complete utility that runs on the computer, but then you need to use the computer.  Maybe do that for big copy jobs and eat the ink cost for the convenience of incidental copies without the computer.